# SQL ROWS CONCAT + JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I'm using Oracle SQL and I want to eliminate the duplicate rows (with the same teacher). I know is a simple task but I am kind of stuck... Please help me.

```
SELECT a.name||' '|| a.first_name AS teacher_name,
       c.course_title AS courses 
FROM teacher a JOIN
     didactic b
     ON a.id_prof = b.id_prof JOIN
     courses c 
     ON b.id_course = c.id_cours 
ORDER BY teacher_name;
```

This is the output:

```
teacher_name    courses
A                sport
A                math
B                one
B                two
```

Comment: USE DISTINCT in your query SELECT

Comment: you have not duplicated  rows ..each row contain different values ..

Comment: I did not express myself correctly. I want so that the teacher name apears only one time and his courses are united in one row with , or ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `listagg()`:

```
SELECT a.name || ' ' || a.first_name AS teacher_name,
       LISTAGG(c.course_title, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.course_title) AS courses 
FROM teacher a JOIN
     didactic b
     ON a.id_prof = b.id_prof JOIN
     courses c 
     ON b.id_course = c.id_cours
GROUP BY a.name || ' ' || a.first_name
ORDER BY teacher_name;
```

Comment: Thx u're a boss. I was trying the listagg but my mistake was on the group by  clause.